# Query: Work Items with closed predecessor or no link at all

Tags: tfs

Some of our tickets form a predecessor/successor relation ship that defines what ticket blocks another.

We have created a query that displays the all tickets which are blocked by other tickets by defining a "Work items and direct links" type of query with a filter like displayed in the image:

[image: blocked query]

Now we want a view of all tickets whose predecessor is closed (=not blocking) or where no predecessor link type exist at all.
This however totally fails for tickets **without** a predecessor (defined by a filter that has NO Predecessor type of link in the "Work items and direct links" type of query). Can this be combined in a query? It seems impossible to have a flat list of work items where the link is taken into account (not displayed, but filtered by) and we have to resort to two query, one "Not Blocked Items" and one "No Predecessors", which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to achieve this in the UI.

Your best option would be to create a list using the API that combines both queries. Or a report in reporting services.

Comment: Thanks for the "disappointing" answer. I hoped for a way without additional programming or services to solve this task. Reporting would create a way to static view of the work items in my opinion.